# how to return a json when using functions.https.onCall

Tags: node.js, typescript

I show two cloud functions below.

The first returns the object in json form. The second returns an object *with a json structure but it is not recognized as a json by my client*.

How should I have Cloud Function 2 return the json?

**Cloud Function 1 using onRequest**

```
export let simpleFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      buildQuestions();
      response.json(questions);
});
```

**Cloud Function 2 using onCall**

```
exports.mathbrain = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
      buildQuestionsA();
      return questions;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to stringify it when returning, like:

```
exports.mathbrain = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
      buildQuestionsA();
      return JSON.stringify(questions);
});
```